# Is there any way to trace or listen that user clicks on any link from a browser, or any chat messenger app or even SMS?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, trace, safe-browsing

I am trying to **trace link click anywhere & in any app** in android device.
For Example, if user clicks links inside WhatsApp - before link redirects to browser, i want to trace it inside my application that link is clicked.

**Is there any way to achieve this??**

I tried Safe Browsing, but its not fulfilling my requirement.
Your suggestions can help me a lot.

Please Let me know if any have solutions for this.

Comment: The one way I can think of is collecting the logs and analyse it. But I am not sure if this is against rule or not. you might want to confirm this one before get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your App yes it is possible to trace user's click events i.e. You can collect analytics data But the same is not possible for whole device i.e. **you can not get trace/click events/analytics data of other apps or entire device**.

It is against the security policy and Google will not allow it.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: How can i trace link is clicked, because on click link will be redirected to browser, then how i can analyze it?

Comment: Please read my answer again.... if that link is inside **your app** then only you can get link clicked event.

Comment: No, listening for link click is possible even from outside of the app. Think of any link of Quora in Chrome browser, if the Quora is installed, you can open it with quora instead of browser.

Comment: @VicJordan yes, i understood it. I am now asking about tracing inside my app itself.

Comment: There are multiple ways to track link clicks inside your app and it is vast question. It depends upon your requirement and your implementation i.e. Do you want to send clicked link info to server for analytics or you want to perform some action within your app. Also how you have implemented the view that is also important so please share relevant source code as well.

Comment: @VicJordan I want to perform an action before link redirects to browser. but i am not clear that how to do it, because on link click it well immediately redirected to browser.